# DocumentSet.Import returns [Exception : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))]

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-set, import, ssom

I'm getting the `[Exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))]` when trying to import documentSet programmatically from a site collection document library to another document lib located in on of his subsites.

PS: this code works perfectly with a FULL Control in site collection but not with contribute or Modification Role.

My question is what is the minimum role to be able to execute the code?

```
SPList publishingList = publishingWeb.TryGetListByUrl("PublishedCases/");
byte[] compressedFile = docSet.Export();
SPContentType secondCt = publishingList.ContentTypes["DOCLIB"];
SPFolder targetFolder = publishingList.RootFolder; 
DocumentSet publishedDocSet = DocumentSet.Import(compressedFile, myitem.Name, targetFolder, secondCt.Id, properties, elevateWeb.CurrentUser);
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did it with Elevate Privileges but still dont know the minimum permissions to be able to create document Set programatically.

```
SPUserToken sysToken = SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID, sysToken))
{    
    using (SPWeb elevatePublishingWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb("Publishing"))
    {
         //Code here ....
         SPList publishingList = 
         elevatePublishingWeb.TryGetListByUrl("PublishedCases/");
         byte[] compressedFile = docSet.Export();
         SPContentType secondCt = publishingList.ContentTypes["CT_DOCLIB"];
         SPFolder targetFolder = publishingList.RootFolder; 
         DocumentSet publishedDocSet = DocumentSet.Import(compressedFile, 
         myitem.Name, targetFolder, secondCt.Id, properties, elevateWeb.CurrentUser);
    }
}
```